# Read a text file until a line contains some string file, then again keep reading next lines until another string is encountered

Tags: c#, filestream, var, using

I have to read a text file and if line contains ".engineering $name" then look for line which contains ".default" and do some operation with this line. I need to keep reading lines until I find ".default" in a set of lines. (This set is like, until I hit next ".engineering"). Loop continue like this again for next ".engineering $name"

Note:
".engineering" keyword is fixed string, $name reading dynamically,
".default" is fixed string,

I am able to do the first part that is reading line which contains ".engineering $name"
I am unable to get logic for next part, finding ".default" until it hits next ".engineering"

Looking for logic or code for this logic in C#. Thank you

Code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string[] def_arr = null;
                        var line1 = reader.ReadLine(); 
                        if (line1.Contains(".engineering " + name + " ") && !reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var nextLine = reader.ReadLine(); // nextLine contains ".default"
                            def_arr = nextLine.Split(' ');
                            def_val = def_arr[1].Replace("\"", "");
                            port_DefaultValues.Add(name + ", " + def_val);                   
                        }
                    }
                }
```

var nextLine is the line containing ".default". I have coded like immidiate next line of finding ".engineering" is having ".default".But it is not always the case. ".default" can be in any line before it hits next ."engineering".

I hope the problem statement is clear.

Comment: Please put your code.

Comment: We can help you solve your problems but for that, you need to show what you have already tried. You need to put your code for that.

Comment: I have added code.

Comment: Use the same logic that you used to find `.engineering`. YOu can use another nested loop for that.

Comment: I am not getting how to put that logic in code. Can you please post code of that? @it's a trap

Answer (score 1):

Try this code -

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] def_arr = null;
                var line1 = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line1.Contains(".engineering " + name + " ") && !reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var nextLine = reader.ReadLine(); // nextLine contains ".default"
                    while (!nextLine.Contains(".default") && !reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    def_arr = nextLine.Split(' ');
                    def_val = def_arr[1].Replace("\"", "");
                    port_DefaultValues.Add(name + ", " + def_val);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have just added a loop that will keep reading the next line until it encounters `.default`. Keep in mind it will throw exception if that is not found in rest of the file.

Comment: Oh yeah it works... But I also need to handle if .default is not present in next set of lines.

Comment: modify the condition of while loop accordingly

Comment: Yes, works partially...Your code is searching ".default" in the next lines until end of file. But I want to search only until it hits next ".engineering". and if not found set def_val as null.

Comment: I have got idea of using goto statement. and I wrote the logic accordingly. It perfectly works now. Thank you all who tried to help me out.